# How to make chat web app use facebook Chat API like Skype?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chat

My customer asked me to develop a web app which include function chat with facebook but as I know, the Facebook Chat API and XMPP things has been deprecated since 04/30/2015.

But the function chat with facebook on Skype still working. Are there have any other approaches beside Facebook Chat API? I would like to hear an clear answer to explain for my customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no alternative to the Chat API. It has been removed and there is no way to implement chat in your App anymore. Skype may have a special deal with Facebook, or they are not upgraded to v2.0 yet - it´s a process that is still going on afaik.

Comment: Facebook's developer relations folks have been pretty clear that no one gets a special deal. We'll see if that's true - Skype's integration should die in the next few weeks if it is.

Comment: @ceejayoz: thanks you all for clear information. The only thing I find strange is Skype did not announce anything about deprecated this function in future.

Comment: you would be surprised how many developers did not know about the upgrade that was announced a year ago and wondered why their stuff did not work anymore ;)